# Probability distribution of the number of nodes in a binary tree

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, trees

Consider [binary trees](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/BinaryTree.html) in which each node has probability $\mathit l \in (0,1)$ of having a left child and probability $\mathit r \in (0,1)$ of having a right child.

What is the probability distribution of the number of nodes in such a binary tree of height $\mathit h$?

This may be a hard question, so I would be grateful for any answer to this question for the simpler case where $\mathit l = \mathit r$ or $\mathit l = 0.5$ and $\mathit r = 0.5$.

Follow up question: what is the probability distribution of the number of nodes in a particular level of such a binary tree of height $\mathit h$?

Motivation: I'm a CS student and I'm interested in comparing the space complexity of a depth-first traversal of such a tree using a stack, $\mathit O(h)$, and the average space complexity of a breadth-first traversal of such a tree using a queue, $\mathit O(the\;maximum\;number\;of\;nodes\;in\;a\;level\;of\;the\;tree)$.

Comment: Regarding your original question: do you mean to condition on the tree surviving to depth $h$? (If the tree is unlucky, it could be stunted immediately since the initial node could fail to have either a left or right child.)

Comment: Yes, that's what I had in mind initially. The tree survives to depth _h_, but not to depth _h + 1_. Perhaps that's not a helpful or useful constraint. I'm interested in the probability distribution of the number of nodes in such a tree given that it has height _h_. But now that I think of it, perhaps I could glean that information from an answer to my original question without conditioning on the tree surviving to a particular depth. Thanks for your interest in my question.